# Outlook 2007 download all GMail messagges from the server

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I recently added a GMail account to Outlook but only half of the mail was downloaded from the server. I assumed it timed out. Is there a way to restart Outlook to continue downloading all messages?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it wasn't a setting in GMail to only download messages more recent than date x?

Comment: Thanks I found the setting. Seems it only downloads to the point POP/IMAP was enabled on the account